# Driving a stepper motor (0K57STH56-2804A) with transistors

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, stepper-motor

I want to drive a stepper motor for a homemade CNC machine but I'm not so experienced so any help would be great. 
I'm working off of this site: https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/Motley/How+to+Drive+a+Stepper+Motor
I was thinking of using 2N3906 transistor in the H-bridge and using either an msp430 launchpad or arduino to control it.
Should i use a different transistors?
Why are they using pnp and npn? I don't really understand the reason given in the website.
Any tips so I don't burn my MCU pins in case i screw up?
Also, any resources that could help with the Darlington pair and transistor calculations would be very appreciated.

Comment: are you certain that you need an H-bridge to operate the stepper motor?

Comment: You should reconsider attempting to design your own controller. This design is not a good choice for an inexperienced person. Controllers are cheap, buy one.

Comment: whats the fun in that? :/

Comment: @jsotola From what I've been reading it's not necessary, any other suggestions other than buying a controller?

Comment: 1.  Settle on what particular step motor(s) you are going to use.  2.  Purchase a controller board or use power MOSFETs.  3.  Figure out what processor you are going to control it with.  4.  Write the software.